# code blocks does not compile on mac OSX

Tags: c++, c, macos, compiler-construction, codeblocks

I have been trying to run code blocks on my mac (10.7.5) and have hit a wall.  I've researched many other threads with people that have had similar problems, but still not able to figure it out.  I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing.

1. downloaded the mac version of codeblocks from codeblocks.org
2. I've installed Xcode from the app store
3. installed the additional developer tools from the apple developer site

when i run a simple program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello dudes");
    return 0;
}
```

the output just says hello world, I know this works, I paste the program into codepad.org and it outputs fine.  the color highlighting in code blocks doesn't seem to work either. just black text and no colors for variables and functions.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I've also tried to set the default compiler to:

1. GNU CC
2. LLVM Clang

Comment: What is your problem?  Does the program fail to compile or give surprising results?  In either case, please provide any error messages, current vs expected output etc.

Comment: Did you install the command line tools from xcode

Comment: the problem is the output is the same no matter what I code in the codeblocks program.  it just says "hello world" rather than what is actually coded, for example in the above it should output "hello dudes".  yes the command line tools in xcode says it's installed when I go to the downloads tab in xcode.  even If there is nothing coded in the codeblock file it still outputs "hello world" when I run and build the program so codeblocks is not properly compiling.  it doesn't give any error messages either.  I'm also coding in C

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can debug the issue. You can add -v flags to both the compilation and the linking in code blocks. This can be done in three places in code blocks, settings->compiler, project settings or build settings.

I ran into a similar issue with compiler problems and solved it through -v debugging. Heres a link to the issue, [C++11 compilation issues in codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961623/c11-compilation-issues-in-codeblocks/25962032#25962032), and the solution. Hopefully that will help walk you through a solution.