# C++11 compilation issues in codeblocks

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I cant seem to get codeblocks 13.12 to compile c++11 correctly in both clang++ and g++. I have attached the -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++ when compiling with clang++. This leads to a linking error. For g++ when you add -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x, the compiler cannot find the random header. When I compiled the code manually in a terminal using both clang++ and g++, none of these errors occurred.

The full linker errors are too long to post so i will just post the information given from the -v invocation. 
In codeblocks using clang++ with -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o bin/Release/p_class_test obj/Release/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Release/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Release/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Release/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Release/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -lstdc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

compiling in terminal using clang++ with -std=c++11 and -stdlib=libc++:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name thread_helper.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/thread_helper-57c077.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name thread_pool.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/thread_pool-321d19.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name hash_methods.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/hash_methods-b28b1b.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name p_classtest.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/p_classtest-ad56a5.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name refmanager.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing/ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/refmanager-d17474.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o nork /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/thread_helper-57c077.o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/thread_pool-321d19.o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/hash_methods-b28b1b.o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/p_classtest-ad56a5.o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T/refmanager-d17474.o -lc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Unfortunately I cant make the comparison between codeblocks g++ and g++ in the terminal.

But based on the output from the two different compilations in clang. It appears codeblocks is not using the libc++ library during the linking step. How do you get codeblocks to use the correct libraries on linking for clang++?

I assume based on the clang problem g++ in codeblocks is using an older c++ 03 library even when telling the compiler to switch to c++11. But unfortunately I dont know how to confirm this.

Comment: You should provide the linker errors (or a sample of them) in your question. Possibly related: [Some C++11 features missing when using Code Blocks 13.12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075852/some-c11-features-missing-when-using-code-blocks-13-12-mingw-4-8-1-and-sfml-2). C++11 gives Eclipse problems too. Its fragile to get things to work properly.

Comment: @jww Thanks I added the error messages and I now have a better idea of the nature of the problem but have no idea how to solve it. I checked out that post and I think we are having different issues. But i am not 100% sure.

Comment: @jww I ended up finding the solution by taking your advice and its mind-blowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to clang++.

Apparently you have to add -stdlib=libc++ as both a compiler flag and a linking flag.

The linkage output turns to

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o bin/Release/p_class_test obj/Release/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Release/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Release/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Release/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Release/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -lc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

which clearly shows the correct library being used.

The g++ problem occurs because even though codeblocks outputs that is it compiling with g++ in actually it using clang++ libraries as part of the compilation and linking process. Though based on the output its not 100% clear if the g++ compiler and its includes are being called. To fix the problem, you need to add -stdlib=libc++ flag for both compilation and linking. As proof that codeblocks on apple is in fact using the clang libraries under the hood, I have attached the output from -v during both linking and compiling and the commands used by codeblocks.

Here is the information for linking:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/p_class_test obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Debug/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o  -v -stdlib=libc++
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o bin/Debug/p_class_test obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Debug/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

And here is the information for compiling:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -v -I/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I/Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool -I/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing -c /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.cpp -o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.8.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name refmanager.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 236.3 -v -gdwarf-2 -coverage-file /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1 -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.8.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -x c++ /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.1 based upon LLVM 3.4svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

After a lot of annoyance I finally figured out what the problem with g++ was on codeblocks. The problem is that codeblocks when calling g++ does not use your executable path. Instead it uses your toolchain executable path in the Compiler settings. My toolchain executable path was set to /usr/bin where the apple version of g++ resides. This version actually calls clang++ through a complex series of calls. All I needed to do to fix the issue was to change the toolchain executable path to /usr/local/bin where my actual gnu compiler resides. After this change, I was able to get rid of -stdlib=libc++ and my compilation and linking readouts are below.

compilation:

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -v -I/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I/Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool -I/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing -c /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.cpp -o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.8.5' '-g' '-std=c++11' '-v' '-I' '/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/' '-I' '/Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool' '-I' '/Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing' '-c' '-o' 'obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/ -I /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool -I /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing -D__DYNAMIC__ /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.cpp -fPIC -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -quiet -dumpbase thread_helper.cpp -mmacosx-version-min=10.8.5 -mtune=core2 -auxbase-strip obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o -g -std=c++11 -version -o /var/folders/k5/ywc_m0js3z3byh3yqwbfmfj00000gn/T//ccVidneY.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 4.3.1, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/p_class_test/
 /Users/zacharykraus/Thread_Pool
 /Users/zacharykraus/Desktop/kmap_testing
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../../include/c++/4.8.1/backward
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks
 /Library/Frameworks
End of search list.
```

linking:

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/p_class_test obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Debug/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o  -v  
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/:/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mmacosx-version-min=10.8.5' '-o' 'bin/Debug/p_class_test' '-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.5 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o bin/Debug/p_class_test -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../.. obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Debug/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
collect2 version 4.8.1
/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.5 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o bin/Debug/p_class_test -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/../../.. obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_helper.o obj/Debug/Thread_Pool/thread_pool.o obj/Debug/Desktop/kmap_testing/hash_methods.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/p_classtest.o obj/Debug/Desktop/p_class_test/refmanager.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-236.4
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 armv6m armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Comment: I finally figured out what the calls above for g++ are doing. They are calling the clang++ compiler using xcode calls. This includes clang's includes and their libraries.